# How to create scalable graphql queries/mutations/fragments structure?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

This question might should't be here, but I am struggle a little bit, how to structure graphql queries/mutations/fragments.(Using ReactJs/Apollo client) I have read many articles and at first tried to create queries near the component (Mostly near page root file) which at first looked ok, but then when you are adding more and more pages which contains some similar components and so on, it getting hard to keep track all the fields everywhere.

As a second option I tried to centralise all queries in one folder, started creating shared fragments, which seems a bit better approach, since you can only change fields only couple of places and it is more or less done. But this approach also getting complex time to time.

1. How to structure queries/mutations/fragments in a scaleable way? Any suggestion or any articles will be helpful.
2. Second, a bit more architectural question: Where do you transform data for view, is it better to normalize using apollo **TypePolicy** or in an higher order component. or sth else maybe ?

I know those are a bit broad questions and depends on use cases (What kind of app you are building and so on), but lets say you are building project, which needs many features to added on the go and it is not some simple presentational website.

Thank you, whoever suggests anything.